# List of subprocesses or multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I wonder which way is the best. I have external program that I want to run multiple instances of. The program doesn't depend on python interpreter at all and get a file as an input. I heard that when you use multiprocessing you run multiple instances of the interpreter, in my case it is waste of RAM. Does anyone know how to implement multiprocessing.Pool like behavior with subprocess.Popen and is it a good idea to lower RAM usage that way?

Usually, I do this to run a single instance:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([executable_path, filename], stdout=log)
while True:
    if proc.poll() is not None: 
         logger.info(f'process is done, {filename} is calculated')
         log.close()
         break
```

I was thinking about:

```
    procs = [subprocess.Popen([executable_path, filename], stdout=log) for filename in filenames]
    ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're on the right path here.  As a point of interest, however, when you launch a new instance of the interpreter, it doesn't double the memory.  If you're running 9 copies of `python.exe`, there's only one copy using physical memory.  The other processes all share the same physical pages.  That's the magic of virtual memory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I managed to do it)
As a matter of fact I got about 50-70 mb of RAM difference when 8 program instances runs simultaneously in favor to plain subprocesses.

Comment: Well, yes, each process is going to have overhead, so it's right to worry about it.  Each will have its own heap, its own stack, and its own copy of any writable data.  I'm just pointing out that you don't get multiple copies of the executable or the shared objects it loads.